# Logout from all other devices when password change laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel web application with a frontend vuejs, there have admin login and customer login, if i change any customer password from admin, then that customer token or session should be expire at that moment. I am using laravel 8 and sanctum. Anybody can help me?

Comment: [This article](https://www.amitmerchant.com/logout-from-everywhere-except-current-device-laravel/) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Just revoke the session for that user? Which is easiest if you have a database based driver. (mysql, redis etc.)

Comment: @onlineThomas revoke session tried but not worked for me. i am using nysql

Comment: Than the middleware isn't checked?

Comment: Yes, That also tried

Comment: great question , I have same issue , still not fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logout
To manually log users out of your application, you can use the logout method on the Auth panel. This will clear the authentication information in the user's session:

```
use IlluminateSupportFacadesAuth;

Auth::logout();
```

Invalidating sessions on other devices
Laravel also provides a mechanism for invalidating and "logging out" user sessions that are active on other devices without invalidating the session on their current device. This feature is typically used when a user changes or updates their password and you want to invalidate sessions on other devices while maintaining the authenticity of the current device.

Before you begin, you must ensure that the IlluminateSessionMiddlewareAuthenticateSession middleware is present and uncommented in your app/Http/Kernel.php middleware group class

web:

```
'web' => [
// ...
\IlluminateSessionMiddleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
// ...
],
```

Then, you can use the logoutOtherDevices method on the Auth frontend. This method requires the user to provide their current password, which your application must accept via an input form:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::logoutOtherDevices($password);
```

When the logoutOtherDevices method is invoked, the user's other sessions will be completely invalidated, meaning that they will be "logged out" of all the guards by which they were previously authenticated.

When using the AuthenticateSession middleware in combination with a custom route name for the login route, you must override the unauthenticated method of your application's exception handler to properly redirect users to your login page.

Comment: Can you please remove the negative note you gave me?